# how to reference the cell the function is called from

Tags: vba, excel

## Situation

I want to create a user defined function that will solve a string equation in a designated cell after replacing the variable in the string with values.

The information is always in two columns.  The top of the first column will contain a formula stored as a string.  The bottom of the first column will contain the UDF.  Between the formula and the UDF will be all the variables from the string formula.  The second column will contain all the numeric values for the variables.

## Problem

I do not know how to select to top of the column of information or the variables above the UDF in an automatic method since I do not know how to define the location of the cell the UDF is placed in.

## Objective

Reference the location of the cell the UDF is in so that the location of the formula cell and the range for the variable cells can be defined.  I am trying to write the UDF in a fashion that I do not have to pass it the address of the formula cell or the variables.  I want it to grab that information on its own based on all the information being immediately adjacent to the cell with the UDF with no gaps.

## What I Have

```
 Option Explicit

 Public Function SolvedEquation() As Long

 Dim FormulaCell As Range
 Dim Equation As String
 Dim VariableRange As Range
 Dim VariableCell As Range
 Dim VariablesLength As Integer
 Dim Variable As String
 Dim VariableValue As Double

 'define FormulaCell as the last nonblank up from the cell the function is called in from a contiguous range(no spaces)
 FormulaCell = Application.ThisCell.End(xlUp).Select

 'define the VariableRange as one up from the cell the function is called to second last cell non blank cell located upward in a contiguous selection (no spaces)
 VariableRange = Range(Cells(Application.ThisCell.Row - 1, Application.ThisCell.Column), Cells(FormulaCell.Row + 1, FormulaCell.Column))

 Equation = FormulaCell.Value

 For Each VariableCell In VariableRange.Cells

     VariablesLength = Len(VariableCell.Value)-1
     Variable = Left(VariableCell.Value, VariablesLength)
     VariableValue = Cells(VariableCell.Row, VariableCell.Column + 1).Value
     Equation = Replace(FormulaCell.Value, Variable, VariableValue)

 Next VariableCell

 SolvedEquation = Evaluate(Equation)

 End Function
```

Suggestions for better coding appreciated (ie choice of range over cells)

## Example of data

[image]

With some code corrections from the individuals below I wound up with this so far.  Where the 177.00 in the cell shows up, it should be reading 176.86.  CORRECTION: got this last problem fixed by redefining the variable type as Chris did in his feedback.

Comment: I'm confused -- you write "I do not know how to define the location of the cell the UDF is placed in" but then you give code which uses `Application.ThisCell` which is exactly how you "define the location of the cell the UDF is placed in". What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well originally I had `selection`.  I did some research and I found someone using `Application .ThisCell` so I tried that but my code is not working and if I recall correctly its crashing at the first `application.thiscell` usage.  As such I did not think I had this coded right.

Comment: `Application.Caller` also works.  Also, you cannot use `Select` in a UDF

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact pros/cons are, but you could also look into `Application.Caller`. That might be preferable if you use it as an array formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code not directly related to `ThisCell`

See inline comments

```
Public Function SolvedEquation() As Variant '~~> allow for Error result
    Dim FormulaCell As Range
    Dim Equation As String
    Dim VariableRange As Range
    Dim VariableCell As Range
    Dim VariablesLength As Integer
    Dim Variable As String
    Dim VariableValue As Double

    'define FormulaCell as the last nonblank up from the cell the function is called in from a contiguous range(no spaces)
    '~~> You must use Set and not use .Select
    '~~> but this wont give you what you want if the cell above ThisCell is blank
    'Set FormulaCell = Application.ThisCell.End(xlUp)
    '~~> use this instead
    If Application.ThisCell.Row <= 2 Then
        ' Function is in row 1 or 2.  What now?
        SolvedEquation = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Application.ThisCell.Offset(-1, 0)) Then
            Set FormulaCell = Application.ThisCell
        Else
            Set FormulaCell = Application.ThisCell.End(xlUp)
        End If
    End If

    'define the VariableRange as one up from the cell the function is called to second last cell non blank cell located upward in a contiguous selection (no spaces)
    '~~> use Set
    '~~> define worksheet
    '~~> simplify
    'VariableRange = Range(Cells(Application.ThisCell.Row - 1, Application.ThisCell.Column), Cells(FormulaCell.Row + 1, FormulaCell.Column))
    With Application.ThisCell
        Set VariableRange = Range(.Offset(-1, 0), FormulaCell.Offset(1, 0))
    End With
    Equation = FormulaCell.Value

    For Each VariableCell In VariableRange.Cells
        VariablesLength = Len(VariableCell.Value) '- 1
        Variable = Left$(VariableCell.Value, VariablesLength) '~~> string version of Left is faster
        VariableValue = VariableCell.Offset(0, 1).Value '~~> simplify
        Equation = Replace$(Equation, Variable, VariableValue) '~~> string version of Replace is faster, continue to work on Equation
    Next VariableCell

    SolvedEquation = Evaluate(Equation)

 End Function
```

That said, your method has the inherent problem that it won't automatically recalculate when its input data changes because there is no reference to the source data in the function call.  A better method is to pass a `Range` parameter to the UDF referencing the equation and the source data, like this

```
Public Function SolvedEquation2(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim Equation As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' copy range data to an array
    dat = rng.Value

    ' Verify size of range
    If UBound(dat, 1) < 2 Or UBound(dat, 2) < 2 Then
        SolvedEquation2 = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Solve equation
    Equation = dat(1, 1)
    For i = 2 To UBound(dat, 1)
        Equation = Replace$(Equation, dat(i, 1), dat(i, 2))
    Next
    ' Use Worksheet version of Evaluate
    SolvedEquation2 = rng.Worksheet.Evaluate(Equation)
 End Function
```

Note: I don't see why you need to manipulate the variables as you do, so I've left that out.  If this *is* needed update your Q with some sample data and expected Equation string and I'll update the A

Based on your sample, formula would be `SolvedEquation2(O129:P133)`

Note: Its better to use the Worksheet version of Evaluate.  [See this link from Charles Williams' website for reason why](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/)

Comment: Improvement - `SolvedEquation2 = rng.Parent.Evaluate(Equation)` or `Evaluate` will use the context of whatever sheet happens to be Active at the time, possible leading to wrong output.

Comment: Chris made some good pointers on basic coding.  I always miss the `set` as I am never sure when its needed.  if memory serves correctly its when you are dealing with cell address/ranges.  Chris also makes a point that if I ever changed changed one of the variable values, or the formula itself, it would not update and recalculate itself.  If this is the case its highly problematic.  I was trying to achieve placing this UDF on multiple worksheets, and multiple locations on a worksheet without having to add the range of information that the calculation is based on each time.

Comment: @Chris I was not aware that offset could be used in such a manner nor that left$/replace$ existed.  Thank you for the education on that.

Comment: @ForwardEd re _if I ever changed changed one of the variable values, or the formula itself, it would not update_ That is exactly the point of including the range reference.  Without it you can use `Ctrl-Alt-F9` to force a full sheet recalc

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, added that and a reference to why it's good

Comment: @TimWilliams and @ChrisNeilsen  In the end great work and kudos to both of you for the assist.  The title of this question is totally misleading as the error wound up being bad programming by me (dang `set`).  Thank you for giving a reason why its better to go with links (autoupdates) and why we need .parent to make sure the UDF is looking at the sheet it is called on.  The reference you gave on evaluate Chris was very...in depth!  A god read despite some of it being over my head.